# I am using foreach inside foreach statement but the values are repeating

Tags: php

This is mycode

```
foreach($html->find('ul.listings li a') as $tvshow)
    $tvshows=preg_replace('/<span[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/span[^>]*>/', '', $tvshow->innertext);
foreach($html->find('li a span.epnum') as $e)

    $query=mysql_query("insert into tvshow(count,author,tvshowname,imdblink,tvshowlink,description,year,image,imagetype,website,date,rating) 
              values('$count','$author','$tvshows','$imdblink','$tvshow->href','$tvshowdescription','$e->innertext','$tvshowname','$tvshowtype','$website','$date','$rating')");
    if(!$query)
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Here $tvshows,$tvshow->href are repeating , i dont want them to repeat. Dont worry abt the code everything is correct only using of two foreach statements makes repeating.Pls make the code not repeating .

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I don't understand what you ask.

Comment: I have edited it pls check it out

Comment: is that direct cut of your code? from that snippet, line 2 is inside the top foreach, and the second foreach is outside with only line 5 being applied to it.  wrap the applying code in {} so the foreach encapsulates the correct code.

Comment: can u pls explain clearly - Flosculus with pls

Answer (score 2):

The power of Curly Brackets...

```
foreach($html->find('ul.listings li a') as $tvshow) {
    $tvshows=preg_replace('/<span[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/span[^>]*>/', '', $tvshow->innertext);

    foreach($html->find('li a span.epnum') as $e) {

        $query=mysql_query("insert into tvshow(count,author,tvshowname,imdblink,tvshowlink,description,year,image,imagetype,website,date,rating) 
                  values('$count','$author','$tvshows','$imdblink','$tvshow->href','$tvshowdescription','$e->innertext','$tvshowname','$tvshowtype','$website','$date','$rating')");
        if(!$query)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
```

It's my suspicion that your foreach's aren't nesting because you didn't enclose them with braces like you should have.

The way you have them written, it would interpret them as completely separate loops.

Loop 1:

```
foreach($html->find('ul.listings li a') as $tvshow) 
    $tvshows=preg_replace('/<span[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/span[^>]*>/', '', $tvshow->innertext);
```

Loop 2:

```
    foreach($html->find('li a span.epnum') as $e) 

        $query=mysql_query("insert into tvshow(count,author,tvshowname,imdblink,tvshowlink,description,year,image,imagetype,website,date,rating) 
                  values('$count','$author','$tvshows','$imdblink','$tvshow->href','$tvshowdescription','$e->innertext','$tvshowname','$tvshowtype','$website','$date','$rating')");
        if(!$query)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Make sense?

Comment: If i use the curly brraces the values are repeating 5 more times each one

Comment: Then I am not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. Your question title is **I am using foreach inside foreach statement but the values are repeating** so I figured the problem was that your foreach loops were actually NOT inside each other. If this doesn't solve your problem, the answer lies somewhere else in your code.

Fankly, the code sample you provided makes me wonder what other syntactically delicious errors you might have made.

Comment: My problem was solved , Tq jdstankosky for trying to help me.Here is the code how i solved.

Comment: Here is the code `code`foreach($html->find('ul.listings li a') as $tvshow)

 {

   $tvshows=preg_replace('/<span[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/span[^>]*>/', '', $tvshow->innertext);
   $query=mysql_query("insert into tvshow(count,author,tvshowname,imdblink,tvshowlink,description,year,image,imagetype,website,date,rating) 
   values('$count','$author','$tvshows','$imdblink','$tvshow->href','$tvshowdescription','','$tvshowname','$tvshowtype','$website','$date','$rating')");

set_time_limit(10000);
 }